# Google Drive API v3 : create folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

I need help with Google Drive API v3. I code in a procedural language (so no Java or PHP or C#), I use WLanguage from the WinDev platform.

I need to create a folder on Google Drive with API v3.

- I obtained my client ID and secret key keys,
- I can connect to Google Drive.

BUT
in my code I can't call functions like `Create` or `Insert`.
I have to put the parameters for creating a folder in the URL.

example:
req.URL="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?name='lili' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
this creates a file named "untitled" in the drive and containing JSON

How to specify in the URL that I want to create a folder?